# Is there a maven3 plugin for jenkins?

Tags: maven, plugins, jenkins

Does jenkins support maven3 via a specific plugin.. Or, is it normal to use the maven 2 plugin with jenkins (even for maven 3 projects)...?

The particular plugin I'm referring to is here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+2+Project+Plugin.

Comment: The page you linked even says "Now supports Maven 3 too." ... There were some alternate plugins for a while, but just using the normal maven 2 plugin should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

The plugin works for maven 3 as well, the actual maven version that is used is what is configured on the job.

To set up installed maven versions go to 'Manage Jenkins' -> 'Configure System' -> 'Maven Installations' and set up.

If more than one maven installation is setup on each job under 'Build' there will be an option for maven version.  If only one maven version is setup that will be used by default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the Maven 2 plugin. Much about Maven 3 is still very "Maven 2"-ish. Even the environment variable `M2_HOME` is still used.